# Is it enough to recovery density matrix for error correction in quantum computing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-computer, quantum-error-correction

When we discuss error correction, we always talk about the recovery of the density matrix of a single qubit. But somehow I feel that this is not enough. Consider a circuit that contains more than 1 qubit, and its current state is $|\psi\rangle$. Now we study the first qubit (and its corresponding errors). We can calculate the (reduced) density matrix $\rho=tr'(|\psi\rangle|\langle\psi|)$, where $tr'$ represents the partial trace of other qubits. Then an error maps the system to $\mathcal{E}(\rho)$. And then we recover it as $\rho=R(\mathcal{E}(\rho))$. However, for a given density matrix, we can always find another representation is $\rho=tr'(|\phi\rangle\langle\phi|)$, with $|\psi\rangle\ne|\phi\rangle$. So maybe the state of the circuit is changed?